# Want to mix layout_centerHorizontal with layout_toLeftOf

Tags: android-layout

I am struggling with a specific layout requirement.

I want a `TextView` that it centred. It is single-line and uses ellipsis if the text is too long. On the same line, to the right of it, I want a small `ImageView`. The presence of the `ImageView` must not affect what the `TextView` thinks is the horizontal centre of the layout. So, although the text might be centred, there is actually less space available to the right of the centre line than to its left.

Within a `RelativeLayout`, the sort-of intuitive thing to use is:

```
<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/image_view_id"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/text_view_id"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/image_view_id"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:singleLine="true"
  android:ellipsize="middle" />
```

but this does not work because you cannot have both `android:layout_toLeftOf` and `android:layout_centerHorizontal`. It behaves as if the `android:layout_centerHorizontal` was not there.

I have also tried using a `LinearLayout` with `android:layout_gravity` without success. Is it possible?

Comment: can you provide with the exact graphical illustration of what you wanna do?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that something close to what I want to achieve is very simple:

```
<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/image_view_id"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/text_view_id"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/image_view_id"
  android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/size_of_image_view"
  android:singleLine="true"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:ellipsize="middle" />
```

Using `android:gravity="center"` with `android:layout_width="match_parent"` centres the text in the available space. It is not perfect as the `marginLeft` is there to keep the text centred within the full layout, thus robbing a little space from its left end but it is good enough for my purposes.